# Discord.js JavaScript discord clients disconnecting and reconnecting for no reason

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Bot disconnects for no reason and reconnects

I am using discord.js v11.60

Image of Logs

[image]

Running a very basic message monitoring script, happens on all my discord bot applications after a while of being running the program.

```
//Inital Login
client.on("ready", () => {
    sendToLogs(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`)
})

client.on('error', err => {
    sendToLogs("Error")
    console.error(err)
    process.exit(1);
});

client.on('reconnecting', message => {
    sendToLogs(`User Reconnecting`)
});

client.on('resume', message => {
    sendToLogs(`Connected ${client.user.tag}`)
});

client.on('disconnect', message => {
    sendToLogs(`User Disconnected`)
    process.exit(1);
});

//On every message
client.on("message", msg => {
    console.log(message.content)
});

client.login(token)
```

Comment: Using Discord.js@11.60 because later updates removed an important functionality

Comment: what is this "important functionality" ?

Comment: Are the messages being logged at least ?

Comment: discord user botting @Tenclea

Comment: it logs for an about an hour and its starts having connection issues at which point it doesn't work

Comment: So you're running this on a user account ?

Comment: This is not a user token, its a bot token, but it also occurs in user tokens as well, this was just the screen shot I had on hand

Comment: Heres a reference image with user tokens
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/613371646937399296/727667486908088360/unknown.png

Comment: wait, you logged in as multiple accounts at the same time ?

Comment: in that example yes, but I've also tried running each independently to no avail

Answer (score 1):

Self botting is against TOS, so discord.js stopped supporting it..

Answer (score -1):

Gave up decided to use the Discord.js-selfbot npm instead, working fine thus far.

Link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord.js-selfbot

Comment: updated version make sure to check for changes in your code, v12 has a few changes in syntax